# Setting text of a label in custom (static) tableviewcell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a TableViewController, which I have set customized cells with 2 labels in each of the cells. I have linked the individual cells to the .m file through the following codes in the .h file :

```
@interface NewChatScreen2 : UITableViewController
{
 IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell1;
 IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell2;
}
@end
```

In an example, I have tagged one of the 2 labels in a particular cell with the number 80001, and I now attempt to change the text of that particular label in cell1 through the following codes :

```
UILabel *cell1NameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell1.contentView viewWithTag: 80001];
cell1NameLabel.text = @"Success namechanged!!";
```

However this does not work. In addition, I have also realised that if I simply point the interface design to the custom class, the customized text in every of the tableviewcells will become blank. I am new to iOS development and wish to ask what is wrong with my code, or the way I am trying to change these custom labels.

Comment: Have you connected the cells with the instances in interface builder?

Comment: Yes I have connected them, they are cell1 and cell2

Comment: did you set the tag value in your nib or storyboard

Comment: I set it under the attribute properties of each tableviewcell, in the storyboard view

Comment: iterate the cell1.contentView suviews and cross check the tags first.

Comment: Hi Ramshad, do you have a sample on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods, and in `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method you must change cell data or appearance.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"YourCellIdentifier";

    YourCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.yourLabel.text = @"some text";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Euroboy for your help, are you able to show me an example how to do this? Currently my cellForRowAtIndexPath method is the default one

Answer (score 0):

check out this

```
UILabel *cell1NameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
cell1NameLabel.text = @"Success namechanged!!";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help iDev, but still doesn't seems to work. I have already set the text of each labels in the customised cells using the interface builder, but when I link it to a custom class, all of the text goes missing, so I am puzzled.

Comment: I am willing to accept your answer, but your current solution does not solve the question posed, I am sorry